# Please check this test token

Tags: solidity, crowdsale, rinkeby

This smart contract is properly deployed on Rinkeby.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x551b092ae227414c5cf7c7e11e70c252e95bedf0

Questions:

1. Why on MetaMask the Beneficiary account address (provided in the code) can't load the majority tokens he should have own?
2. Where all the 17998500 tokens that should be in balance of the address holder? Havent they reached? The investors funds are received.
3. Why on Read Smart Contract it says
   *Sorry, we were unnable to retrieve a valid ContractABI for this contract. 
   Unable to read contract information*

Comment: For 3. you need to verify the contract, in the page https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x55901248f9ab599e250c7b5f4627e8f6ec67ed94#code there's a "Verify and Publish" link.

Comment: Ok.what is confusing me is that the adress used as owner in the code and one receiving funds  is different from the address that is under Contract holder. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to `add the token` in metamask so that it would show the details properly.
2. All the transactions in this contract seems to have failed (https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x551b092ae227414c5cf7c7e11e70c252e95bedf0)
3. As Ismael said, you will have to verify the contract so that it would show the details.

Comment: I do Add Token. It doesnt add, even though it finds token name after pasting address

Comment: Try restarting the browser to see the tokens attached.

Comment: Didnt work. 
what is confusing me is that the adress used as owner in the code and one receiving funds is different from the address that is under Contract holder. Why so?

Comment: Ignore metamask, if you can confirm the tokens in rinkey.etherscan then you are pretty much fine.

Comment: yea but how should the token creating address to send tokens to people? He doesnt have the balance of all tokens remaining.

Comment: This address `0x55901248f9ab599e250c7b5f4627e8f6ec67ed94` is the owner of the contract. isn't it? Check here https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x55901248f9ab599e250c7b5f4627e8f6ec67ed94 that seems to have about 17M tokens remaining

Comment: that address turns out to be contract address not the wallet address of the owner. thats the issue. the wallet addres does receive funds though.

Comment: With reference to here https://www.ethereum.org/token, if you have not added the construction function like below, the owner will never receive the tokens  ` function MyToken(uint256 initialSupply) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    }`

Comment: I assume I have. It was deployed based on this contract. Please check
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/33811/25297

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70583/discussion-between-buzzmuzz5-and-rajesh).