# Differences between these smart contract addresses?

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix

Here is another issue for beginners:

1. Please check this token page. What are the differences between Token Holder address and the one that says Contract Address?

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x88a230a9222cb3655acb7278077f02641f6273b5?a=0xf6be2556b613acbea6bc322eebfe7574fe74a4d0

Arent we supposed to send funds to "Contract Address" (one on right)?

When I send ETHs to Contract Address one, theres Gas Limit problem. But for Token Holder address it goes fine.

1. And why the beneficiary address in the code doesnt get all deployed tokens (he receives ETHs though)?

Note: contract is in Crowdsale phase until 23 dec

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Token holder is the address that owns tokens from a smart contract ERC20.

> Arent we supposed to send funds to "Contract Address" (one on right)?

It depends. If the contract has not a payable fallback function that will accept funds, sending funds to it will fail. You should  check how the token sales are being hold. Sending funds to a smart contract is not the standard pattern to buy tokens.

You may check Grid+ token sale contract. It is a good recent example.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x94dc1cf66c8fd62ef3bd7da53f47423862839823#code

It has a function called `purchaseToken`. You will send funds to this function and it will calculate how much tokens you´ve just bought and transfer it to you.

Here we have a good example and deep analysis of token sales:
http://vitalik.ca/general/2017/06/09/sales.html

> The last few months have seen an increasing amount of innovation in token sale models. Two years ago, the space was simple: there were capped sales, which sold a fixed number of tokens at a fixed price and hence fixed valuation and would often quickly sell out, and there were uncapped sales, which sold as many tokens as people were willing to buy. Now, we have been seeing a surge of interest, both in terms of theoretical investigation and in many cases real-world implementation, of hybrid capped sales, reverse dutch auctions, Vickrey auctions, proportional refunds, and many other mechanisms

Comment: thanks for comments.
BUyer receives his tokens when he sends ETHs. But the owner address (address given to code) doesnt get all tokens after deployment. Thats the problem.

Comment: 0x9C8E781d3b3f72c7e62488a9F2FcB9B40D73DeAe created the contract. 0xF6BE2556B613ACBeA6Bc322EEBFE7574fe74A4d0 is the token contract and it has 991,950 HEY. I couldn´t find the contract owner and I am not sure why contract owner should have all the tokens without the contract source file

Comment: bascially, contract was deployed based on this (after correction discussed there).
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/33811/25297